# Skype Bot OAuth error that wasn't happening before

Tags: oauth, botframework, skype, microsoft-skype-bot

I previously had a Skype bot able to post messages using the API.

But on 11/17/17 I started getting this error on every attempt, and as a result, no message gets posted. I haven't changed anything.

```
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 401 Client Error: The provided 'OAuth' ticket failed authentication. for url: https://apis.skype.com/v2/conversations/[conversation]/activities/
```

The process I use is to get an access token witha post to https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token
and then to use that token to post a message to https://apis.skype.com/v2/conversations/[conversation]/activities/

It's able to get the token fine, but then when the message post is called, it raises the above exception.

Comment: Have you hard coded https://apis.skype.com/ into your bot?  You should use the incoming messages serviceUrl to construct a reply.  Skype messages will have a serviceUrl of https://smba.trafficmanager.net/apis/

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am hardcoding `"Host":"apis.skype.com"` into the header, and using the hardcoded URL as well. I'm not sure how to get the "incoming messages serviceUrl", how can I do that? All I am able to get right now is a token.

Comment: the incoming message has a serviceUrl that should be used to reply: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-send-and-receive-messages#send-the-reply

Comment: Hmm. The bot isn't set up to receive messages from users; it only posts messages itself.

Comment: Have you tried https://smba.trafficmanager.net/apis as the base url, and /v3/conversations/{conversationid}/activities/{activityid} ?  Your code posted above is using https://apis.skype.com as the base url and /v2/conversations/{conversationid}/activities

Comment: I get `HTTPError: 401 Client Error: Unauthorized for url: https://smba.trafficmanager.net/apis/v3/conversations/[conversationid]/activities/`  ...but perhaps that's because I don't have an activityid to pass in?

Comment: My skype bot used only SEND messages and keep returning 401 last few days.
Changing send url to https://smba.trafficmanager.net/apis/v3/conversations /{}/activities didn't get any result
I get auth token successful but it's still doesnt work 
`('{"message":"Authorization has been denied for this request."}', 401)`

Comment: May be is there any other new auth endpoint? Because in Docs so many new things about API v3 but Auth section still point to login.microsoftonline.com/botframework.com/oauth2/v2.0/token

Comment: @twasbrillig activityId only needs to send **reply** . In our case when bot works just as notification manager we keep using v3/conversations /{}/activities , with new baseurl I guess only. 
 But it's still doesnt work

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've faced with exactly the same problem and this worked for me:

I left all send messages endpoint as is for v2, BUT in token generation POST payload I've changed `'scope' -> 'https://api.botframework.com/.default'`

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much!! (I had it as `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default` before.)